# ORA-01843: not a valid month : to_timestamp(sysdate,'DD-MON-RR HH.MI.SSXFF AM')

Tags: oracle, date

I've faced a problem during insert. Here is the problem:

```
insert into AI_FILEANDFOLDER
(ID,DESCRIPTION,OWNER,ROOTFOLDER,CATEGORY,PATH,NAME,TYPE,VERSIONNO,VISIBILITYTYPE,
VISIBLE,CREATEDBY,CREATEDON,ISDEFAULT,LASTUPDATEDON,LASTUPDATEDBY,ISARCHIVABLE,ISARCHIVED,ISPURGEABLE,ISPURGED) 
values (1,'Documents parent folder','Demo','/Demo',null,'/','Documents','folder',1,'PVT',1,'Demo',to_timestamp(sysdate,'DD-MON-RR HH.MI.SSXFF AM'),'1',to_timestamp(sysdate,'DD-MON-RR HH.MI.SSXFF AM'),'Demo',0,0,0,0)
```

I have faced an exception at phrase `to_timestamp(sysdate,'DD-MON-RR HH.MI.SSXFF AM')` that:

> ORA-01843: not a valid month

Answer (score 3):

You want to use [`SYSTIMESTAMP`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions173.htm)

```
insert into AI_FILEANDFOLDER
(ID,DESCRIPTION,OWNER,ROOTFOLDER,CATEGORY,PATH,NAME,TYPE,VERSIONNO,VISIBILITYTYPE,
VISIBLE,CREATEDBY,CREATEDON,ISDEFAULT,LASTUPDATEDON,LASTUPDATEDBY,ISARCHIVABLE,ISARCHIVED,ISPURGEABLE,ISPURGED) 
values (1,'Documents parent folder','Demo','/Demo',null,'/'
    ,'Documents','folder',1,'PVT',1,'Demo'
    ,systimestamp,'1',systimestamp,'Demo',0,0,0,0)
```

Comment: Thanks @Gurwinder but i required 'DD-MON-RR HH.MI.SSXFF AM' in this format

Comment: @Mayur What are the datatypes of columns `createdon` and `lastupdatedon`?

Comment: Then my answer is correct. While retrieving the result though, you can use to_char to get the result in any required format.

Comment: But i need to inset as 29-DEC-16 10:58:48.000000000 AM not 29-12-16 10:58:48.000000000 AM. during retrieving i cannot change it required to change in more than 1000 query

Comment: the timestamp is not stored as `29-DEC-16 10:58:48.000000000 AM` or any other format. It's totally different. it's your NLS parameters (set in probably you sql developer) which show the values as - `29-12-16 10:58:48.000000000 AM`

Comment: Just insert the row and while retrieving, use to_char(createdon, 'DD-MON-RR HH.MI.SSXFF AM' )